# How to use @TextboxFor in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC. Please Help me how I can bind `foreach` values to `TextboxFor`
**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var initialData = new[] {
             new Gift { Name = "Tall Hat", Price = 39.95 },
             new Gift { Name = "Long Cloak", Price = 120.00 },
          };
            return View(initialData);

        }
```

**.cshtml**

```
 @foreach (Gift a in Model)
 {
     @Html.TextboxFor(a=>a.Name)
 }
```

I'm getting error here.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Can you please share the error too ? Yor model may null ?

Comment: CS0136: A local or parameter named 'a' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: @David any Help from you

Comment: Can you share parrent scope code for this foreach.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` is not recommended in this context, because lambda semantics makes posting data back with correct parameter names difficult. What is recommended is to switch to simple `for` loop:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
 {
     @Html.TextboxFor(m => m[i])
 }
```

For clarity, `m` here refers to the model your view is parametrized with. Also note that this obviously assumes your model is a list or an array, so that you can index it.